# The heat flow and existence of geodesic

Tags: partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry

I'm reading Jost's Riemannian Geometry and Geometric Analysis and in section 1.6 during the proof of the first step in theorem 1.6.1 it says

> Step 1 is a general result from the theory of partial diﬀerential equations which follows
> by linearizing the equation at t = 0 and applying the implicit function theorem in Banach spaces, see §A.3. Therefore, we shall not discuss this here any further.

In appendix A.3

> What one can deduce from Theorem A.3.2, however,
> is the short time existence of solutions when the linearization of the diﬀerential
> operator satisﬁes the assumptions of that theorem. This follows by linearization
> and the implicit function theorem.

Could someone provide me a resource for a more detailed way to linearize equation 1.6.2 ($\Gamma_{jk}^i u_s^ju_s^k$)?

For reference, the theorem and related parts are

[Theorem statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySsqP.png)

[First part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fIzE.png)

[Development](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62cDz.png)

Comment: It should be helpful to state the full Theorem, and which Banach spaces are involved: not everybody has immediate access to the reference.

Comment: @Didier, good point, just added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose first that the solution you are looking for lives in $\Bbb R^n$ and that you are given the system
$$
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial t} &= F(x,u(x,t)),\\
u(x,0) &= u_0(x).
\end{cases}
$$
Its linearization around $u_0$ ("at $t=0$") is the equation
$$
\dfrac{\partial v(x,t)}{\partial t} = L(x) v(x,t),
$$
where $L(x)$ is the linear operator (depending only on $x$) defined by
$$
L(x) v(x) = \left.\dfrac{\partial F\left(x,u_0(x)+tv(x)\right)}{\partial t}\right|_{t=0}.
$$
We can interpret this latter expression as the Fréchet derivative $L(x) = D_2F_{(x,u_0(x))}$.
If you are not looking for a solution in $\Bbb R^n$ but in a manifold, this latter property is used to define the linearization.

In your explicit case, looking at
$$
F^i(s,u) = \partial^2_{ss} u^i + \Gamma^i_{jk}(u)\partial_su^j\partial_su^k
$$
gives the linearization
$$
L^iv = \partial^2_{ss}v^i + \partial_{\ell}\Gamma^i_{jk}(u_0)v^{\ell} \partial_su^j_0\partial_su_0^k + \Gamma^i_{jk}(u_0)\partial_sv^j\partial_su_0^k + \Gamma^i_{jk}(u_0)\partial_su_0^j \partial_sv^k,
$$
which is indeed linear in $v$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there any book that cover this process or have more examples ?

Comment: @watss Quoting Jost, at the end of Appendix A.3: "A reference for parabolic differential equations and systems is *Linear and quasilinear equations of parabolic type*, Ladyzhenskaya, Solonnikov and Ural’ceva. For a
textbook treatment, we refer to *Partial differential equation*, Jost."